# Need help to solve problems when implementing structure compare view in eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse, merge, compare, rcp

I've been working on the implementation of a structure compare and merge function of a text based file through eclipse compare infrastructure.

Through this [FAQ link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_can_I_use_and_extend_the_compare_infrastructure?), I've got a basic idea of how to do it. And [this more detailed guide](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/compare_contentviewer.htm) helped me to understand more about how to implement the structure viewer using `StructureCreator`.

So basically I extended the `structureCreators` extension point and created my own `StructureCreator` using the tree structure from the parsing result of the text file. Yes, our special language format in the text file can be parsed into a tree structure. And so far I can see the correct structural differences of two files in the tree view in the upper part of the whole comparing window.

**However, my problem is that when I double click a tree node, it does not bring up the differences of the nodes in the two panes in the lower part of window.** It just displays nothing, not like when comparing two java files in the eclipse.

I think this problem has something to do with the shared document as the guide says:

> For text based inputs, clients should subclass the StructureCreator
>   class. This will enable the use of a shared document between multiple
>   editors open on the same file. Subclasses of StructureCreator that
>   provide syntax highlighting must implement both the
>   getDocumentPartitioner() and getDocumentPartitioning90 methods to
>   support shared documents.

However, I don't know where went wrong. Do I need to extend more extension points such as `structureMergeViewers` to make it work or just to add more stuff in the subclass of `StructureCreator` to make it right?

And If I want to support syntax highlighting, What more things do I need to do? the above quoted instructions are too simple to follow.

I wish some eclipse dev experts with such experience can help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I need to return an object that extends DocumentRangeNode from StructureCreator.createStructureComparator(...). This enables the lower part of the compare window to display the differences of the selected node.

I have created a post to share [my lessons from the eclipse structure viewer creation](http://www.mytechtip.com/2012/03/eclipse-structure-compare.html).